# Ionic 4 - getting ElementRef property on Directive

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, elementref

I need get ElementRef value in a Directive to apply dynamically a class to the element.

My Directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[scrolling]'
})

export class ScrollingDirective {

  constructor(public renderer: Renderer2, public el: ElementRef) {
    console.log(this.el);
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement.scrollWidth);
    if (el.nativeElement.scrollWidth > el.nativeElement.clientWidth) {
      this.renderer.addClass(el.nativeElement, 'scrollear');
    }  
  }

}
```

Then I assign the directive to a DOM's element:

```
<ion-label scrolling>hello world</ion-label>
```

The problem is that in the constructor of the directive I cannot receive the values ​​of the element, however, with console.log I can see the values ​​correctly, but I can't get them.

I need to retrieve these values, but when referencing them the value is 0.

[image: console.log(this.el);]

Comment: Works for me here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v6w63v.

Comment: exactly same code but doesn't work in my case :(
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot get the values in the constructor because it hasn't rendered yet. Try accessing them in `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: try this:

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit');
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement.clientWidth);
  }

and getting:

ngAfterViewInit
0

:(

any suggestion?